# column renaming with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to rename a column using `dplyr::rename`, but failing..

```
library(dplyr)

cars %>% 
  filter(speed > 20) %>% 
  rename(speed = new_speed)

# Error: Unknown variables: new_speed.
```

Any ideas what's wrong there?

Comment: It should be `rename(new_speed = speed)` because, you are giving new name to variable `speed`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the other way

```
cars %>% 
  filter(speed > 20) %>% 
  rename(new_speed = speed)
```